# Unable to retrieve special characters like ® while using HttpServletResponseWrapper

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8, java-8

I am unable to retrieve a special character (®) while using `HttpServletResponseWrapper`, processing the response with `RequestDispatcher` include.

I tried setting the character encoding to `UTF-8` and also did try the configuration changes in `WEB.xml`. Still I am not able to retrieve the character and moreover, I am not even seeing an encoded string in place of the character.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] or the code where you recieve and extract the data, else it's quite difficult to help you

Comment: Did you try to use setCharacterEncoding in ServletResponse? Maybe if you give some example it will be more easy to see what is wrong...